# how to retrieve data from Siebel to mdb

Tags: siebel

I am a newbie with Siebel CRM. So I need to retrieve data separate by object (account, lead, contact, …) into Access (mdb). Please advice me how to and any advise.. Thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

There's no out-of-the-box tool for exporting your data to an Access database.  However, Siebel data is stored in some RDBMS -- which one depends on your setup.  You'll need to import data from your Siebel database to the Access database using an ODBC connection.  Here's an [example](http://eis.bris.ac.uk/~ccmjs/oracle_to_access.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Most entities are stored in their own tables - S_PARTY and S_ORG_EXT hold Account data; S_OPTY holds Leads, etc. - see Siebel Tools or the Siebel Data Model Reference.

Each of the tables also has it's own filters to divide the tables records by type (e.g. Contacts vs. Employees) and the relationships between tables is not totally clear from the database level (you'll need your local Siebel developer for that)

if you don't have a local Siebel developer then you might be able to spool SQL from the dedicated web client and figure out how tables are related from there - but this would be quite a lot of work

- B

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question what level of data detail you need to get.

If you want to get basic, GUI-available details, then most list views in the screens (Activities, Leads, Contacts, Accounts, Opportunities, etc) allow you to export to a *.CSV format file the list of records shown in the view based on whatever query you have run. You can then import the *.csv into MS Access.

If you need the details like primary keys or foreign keys, or related tables, you will need to use a SQL tool and workout queries to get that data out of the server database as others have here mentioned.